# Why won't sdkman change my default java version?

Tags: java, sdkman

This problem persisted after updating and upgrading sdkman, deleting .sdkman and reinstalling it, and uninstalling java packages and reinstalling them.

```
me@myMachine myProject $ sdk default java 8.0.252.hs-adpt
Default java version set to 8.0.252.hs-adpt
me@myMachine myProject $ sdk default java
Default java version set to 11.0.7.hs-adpt
```

`sdk current java` and `java -version` reflect the change but reverts back to 11.0.7 upon closing and reopening terminal, or opening a different window or app.

Answer (score 5):

I just happen to get that error, on Manjaro ..after an update of the S.O., so the error is the `/usr/bin/java` now points to the default java installed on the update.

So i just removed all Java versions installed on the updates cause I need only to use the sdkman.

```
sdk home java 8.0.232.hs-adpt
```

With this i can see where are the candidates on my case:

```
/home/xxxx/.sdkman/candidates/java/8.0.232.hs-adpt
```

So after removed all java: i run `java -version` i found there is no java anymore.

So i force update sdkman

```
sdk selfupdate force
```

Then after install

```
source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
```

And to be sure i ran :

```
ls -al /usr/bin/java
```

> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 37 may 16  2020 /usr/bin/java -> /usr/lib/jvm/default-runtime/bin/java

and now it points to where sdkman supposed to:

And thats it now i can change versions again with sdkman.

```
sdk use java 11.0.5.hs-adpt
```

Comment: Yes. This is on the right path. In my case, I had installed Java via Homebrew prior to starting to use `sdkman` so I needed to uninstall with `brew uninstall java` first and then immediately afterwards, `java -version` and `which java` was correctly showing the Java version from `sdkman`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If SDKMAN! is not persistently setting the default Java version even after running `sdk default java <version>` and you're experiencing a reset upon closing and reopening the terminal, there might be an issue with the initialization process or your shell configuration. Here are a few steps you can take to troubleshoot and resolve the issue:

#### 1. Check Shell Profile:

Ensure that the `sdkman-init.sh` script is being sourced in your shell profile (e.g., `.bashrc`, `.zshrc`, or equivalent). Open your shell profile using a text editor:

```bash
nano ~/.bashrc   # or .zshrc or .bash_profile, depending on your shell
```

Add the following line at the end of the file:

```bash
source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
```

Save the file and restart your terminal or run `source ~/.bashrc` (or the appropriate file for your shell).

#### 2. Verify Configuration:

Check the content of your shell profile to ensure it's correctly sourcing the `sdkman-init.sh` script. Also, verify that there are no conflicting configurations that might interfere with SDKMAN! settings.

#### 3. Check for Other Java Environment Variables:

Make sure there are no conflicting `JAVA_HOME` or `PATH` entries pointing to a different Java installation. These environment variables could override SDKMAN! settings.

#### 4. SDKMAN! Self-Update:

Ensure that SDKMAN! itself is up-to-date. Run the following commands:

```bash
sdk selfupdate
sdk update
```

#### 5. Use the `sdk env` Command:

Run the `sdk env` command after setting the default Java version. This command outputs the shell configuration necessary for SDKMAN! to function correctly. Ensure that this output is being sourced in your shell profile.

```bash
sdk default java 8.0.252.hs-adpt
sdk env
```

#### 6. Check for Shell Session Persistence:

Some systems have settings that prevent certain commands from being executed when starting a new terminal session. Ensure that the configurations in your shell profile are being applied to new sessions.

After making these changes, restart your terminal and check if the default Java version persists. If the issue persists, there may be additional details specific to your environment that need to be addressed. Feel free to provide more information for further assistance.